# Turning a list of rows into columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
foo = ['123','123','123]
```

I am attempting to turn `foo` into:

```
revisedfoo = ['111', '222', '333']
```

This in effect is turning the "rows" into "columns":

```
111
222
333
```

I have attempted something along these lines:

```
    for j in range(len(foo)):
        for i in range(len(foo)):
            revisedfoo.append(foo[i][j])
```

But it leaves me with:

```
revisedfoo = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3']
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zip()` and the star operator:

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(*foo)]
['111', '222', '333']
```

#### Explanation

---

`zip(*foo)` ["unzips" foo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), e.g.:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> list(zipped)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> x2, y2 = zip(*zip(x, y))
>>> x == list(x2) and y == list(y2)
True
```

So in this case:

```
# You need to call `list()`, because `zip()` returns
#     an iterator in Python 3.x
>>> list(zip(*foo))
[('1', '1', '1'), ('2', '2', '2'), ('3', '3', '3')]
```

Then on each of these sub-elements (tuples), we want to join the individual elements into one string.  `''.join(seq)` is the standard way to go about this.